# How to add a DataFrame in one column of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a dataframe to store informations on samples. Some of my columns label have the format index:subindex. Is there a better way of doing that? I was looking at pd.MultiIndex but my subindices are specific to the index.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.random(size=(1234, 6)),
    columns=['ID',
             'Charge:pH2', 'Charge:pH4', 'Charge:pH6',
             'Extinction:Wavelength200nm', 'Extinction:Wavelength500nm'])
```

I would like to be able to call `df.loc[:, 'ID']` or `df.loc[:, 'Charge']` or `df.loc[:, ('Charge', 'pH6')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best is create index or Multiindex with not columns possible split (with no splitter) and then create `MultiIndex` by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True`:

```
np.random.seed(2019)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.random(size=(3, 6)),
    columns=['ID',
             'Charge:pH2', 'Charge:pH4', 'Charge:pH6',
             'Extinction:Wavelength200nm', 'Extinction:Wavelength500nm'])

df = df.set_index('ID')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(':', expand=True)
print (df)
            Charge                          Extinction                
               pH2       pH4       pH6 Wavelength200nm Wavelength500nm
ID                                                                    
0.903482  0.393081  0.623970  0.637877        0.880499        0.299172
0.702198  0.903206  0.881382  0.405750        0.452447        0.267070
0.162865  0.889215  0.148476  0.984723        0.032361        0.515351
```

Solution with not set `ID` in index is possible, but get `NaN` for second level for not splitted columns names:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(':', expand=True)
print (df)
         ID    Charge                          Extinction                
        NaN       pH2       pH4       pH6 Wavelength200nm Wavelength500nm
0  0.903482  0.393081  0.623970  0.637877        0.880499        0.299172
1  0.702198  0.903206  0.881382  0.405750        0.452447        0.267070
2  0.162865  0.889215  0.148476  0.984723        0.032361        0.515351
```

Last select by columns names, also is possible use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) if want select by second level:

```
print (df['Charge'])
               pH2       pH4       pH6
ID                                    
0.903482  0.393081  0.623970  0.637877
0.702198  0.903206  0.881382  0.405750
0.162865  0.889215  0.148476  0.984723

print (df.xs('Charge', axis=1, level=0))
               pH2       pH4       pH6
ID                                    
0.903482  0.393081  0.623970  0.637877
0.702198  0.903206  0.881382  0.405750
0.162865  0.889215  0.148476  0.984723

print (df.xs('pH4', axis=1, level=1))
            Charge
ID                
0.903482  0.623970
0.702198  0.881382
0.162865  0.148476
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [MultiIndex.from_tuple](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.random(size=(1234, 6)),
    columns=['ID','Charge:pH2', 'Charge:pH4', 'Charge:pH6','Extinction:Wavelength200nm', 'Extinction:Wavelength500nm'])

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(map(tuple, df.columns.str.split(':')))

print(df.head(10))
```

**Output**

```
         ID    Charge       ...            Extinction                
        NaN       pH2       ...       Wavelength200nm Wavelength500nm
0  0.301592  0.137384       ...              0.074137        0.339948
1  0.737711  0.557524       ...              0.813727        0.586845
2  0.615398  0.529687       ...              0.148700        0.466916
3  0.411509  0.725513       ...              0.380019        0.876992
4  0.031172  0.623944       ...              0.311610        0.488207
5  0.022140  0.450630       ...              0.422927        0.479094
6  0.119681  0.221624       ...              0.710848        0.719201
7  0.252039  0.632321       ...              0.453235        0.952687
8  0.379501  0.356493       ...              0.141977        0.028836
9  0.249950  0.316020       ...              0.307337        0.881437

[10 rows x 6 columns]
```

All the required indexing schemes work:

```
print(df.loc[:, 'ID'].shape)
print(df.loc[:, 'Charge'].shape)
print(df.loc[:, ('Charge', 'pH6')].shape)
```

**Output**

```
(1234, 1)
(1234, 3)
(1234,)
```